# How to set hard conditions for source nat rules in nftables?

Tags: linux, nat, nftables

There is only one table on the server - "nat" and it contains only two chains: "prerouting" and "postrouting". IP forwarding is enabled. I'm trying to set more specific conditions for the source nat rule. When I set the classic rule :

```
nft add rule nat postrouting ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 oif eth0 snat 1.2.3.4
```

everything works fine. But I'd like to specify also the interface where it's located for the network "saddr 192.168.1.0/24".

```
nft add rule nat postrouting **iif eth1** ip saddr 192.168.1.0/24 oif eth0 snat 1.2.3.4
```

When I enter this command, the program accepts it and the rule appears in the table. But the traffic doesn't go. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature *also* requires kernel >= 5.5 for adequate netfilter support. Description in [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.5):

> Linux 5.5 [was released](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/26/232) on 26 Jan 2020
>
> [...]
>
> - netfilter
>
>   - Support iif matches in POSTROUTING [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=28f8bfd1ac948403ebd5c8070ae1e25421560059)

From the commit:

> **netfilter: Support iif matches in POSTROUTING**
>
> Instead of generally
> passing NULL to NF_HOOK_COND() for input device, pass skb->dev which
> contains input device for routed skbs.
>
> Note that iptables (both legacy and nft) reject rules with input
> interface match from being added to POSTROUTING chains, but nftables
> allows this.

From the description, before this commit, the input interface was not provided by netfilter and the `iif` expression never matched.

Comment: apparently so .. I turned out to be 5.4 version :)

Comment: Not in my answer but I double checked it worked (on kernel 5.10). Also for iptables (at least iptables-nft, didn't test with iptables-legacy) despite the commit's comment, as a workaround, using `-i eth1` in an additional user chain called from POSTROUTING rather than using directly `-i eth1` in POSTROUTING would work too.

Comment: updated to 5.11 and it worked)
It's a pity that this does not work with the prerouting chain.

Comment: I mean, specify in the rule from which interface and from which network you can forward to which interface and which ip.For example like this : 

nft add rule nat prerouting iif ens33 ip daddr 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dport { 80, 443 } oif ens33 dnat to 192.168.200.200:8888

Comment: check this, but keep in mind that NAT alters addresses, which alters routing decision which might render result of the just-made FIB lookup not the final routing decision and thus "false". Probably not to be used in a NAT chain: https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#FIB_EXPRESSIONS